# Select count of all child rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table `articles` in which I have organized the content in the following hierarchy:

1. Section
2. Subject
3. Chapter
4. Post

Each item from the above is on a row having fields: `id`, `parent`, `name` etc.

The post row `parent` equals chapter row `id`, chapter row `parent` equals subject row `id` and subject row `parent` equals section row `id`.

I don't have taller hierarchy than above.

I need to select the list of subjects in the a given section along with the count of all children of each subject. The count is the sum of number of descendant chapters and their descendants which are posts.

My brother helped me with the following select query. However it is relatively slow at ~0.6 seconds.

```
SELECT
    subjects.id,
    subjects.name,
    subjects.link,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT posts.id)
    FROM
        articles AS chapters,
        articles AS posts
    WHERE
        chapters.parent = subjects.id AND(
            posts.parent = chapters.id OR posts.parent = subjects.id
        )
    ) AS child_count
FROM
    articles AS subjects
WHERE
    subjects.parent = 62
```

I need help with improving the performance please.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: If it is slow, then you probably forgot to create an **index** on `parent`.

Comment: You said *"post row `parent` equals chapter row `id`"*, so why `posts.parent = subjects.id`? That will never map anything, since a subject cannot be the parent of a post.

Comment: wow just added an index on parent column. and it now processes in 0.02 seconds @Andreas thanks !!

Comment: Regarding that `posts.parent = subjects.id` I think  we had to add that because otherwise it only counted posts. I needed to count chapter rows as well. Even though it says `posts.parent` it is actually the chapter row because the parent is subject. Weird how the query works lol @Andreas

Comment: Sad that it is being voted to close because this question is different from the one posted as possible duplicate. I am concerned with the count of children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This logic is hard to follow, but I think you intend:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.link,
       ( (SELECT COUNT(*)  -- count children
          FROM articles c
          WHERE c.parent = s.id
         ) +
         (SELECT COUNT(*)  -- count grandchildren
          FROM articles c JOIN
               articles p
               ON p.parent = c.id
          WHERE c.parent = s.id
         )
    ) as child_count
FROM articles s
WHERE s.parent = 62;
```

Then for this query, you want an index on `articles(parent)`.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Your brother needs to learn how to write correct SQL as well.
- `COUNT(DISTINCT)` can be more expensive than just `COUNT()`.
- `OR`s in the correlation or `ON` clause can impede the optimizer.

Comment: works perfectly and takes 0.015 seconds ... thank you :)